# How to replace in variable strings inside azure-pipelines.yaml?

Tags: string, azure-pipelines

I want to set `VersionSuffix` from `Build.Sourcebranch` but this fails since `SourceBranch` contains `refs/heads/<branchname>`.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  condition: succeeded()
  inputs: 
    command: 'pack'
    versioningScheme: ByPrereleaseNumber
    majorVersion: '0' 
    minorVersion: '1' 
    patchVersion: '1' 
    packTimezone: 'utc' 
    buildProperties: VersionSuffix=$(Build.SourceBranch)-$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

I just want to add `.Replace('/','_')` and a few similar statements to `$(Build.SourceBranch)`, but I can't find anything in the expression syntax on how to do that.

It didn't work to send in another string (i.e. `VersionSuffixRaw`) and create the `VersionSuffix` with `String.Replace` inside the .csproj; it just got ignored for some reason.

**Note**: There is `Build.SourceBranchName` which has the last part of a branchname, so if `SourceBranch` is `refs/heads/feature/foo`, `SourceBranchName` will be `foo`. However a branch namd `feature/JIRA-123_foo_unittest` will not work since _ is not valid in a version string.

Comment: So if sometimes you have `_` in the branch name, what you want to do? to replace it to...?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

For others finding this through searches, there is now a replace expression: [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#replace)

```
variables:      
  branch: $[replace(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], '/', '-')]
```

Comment: I couldn't get this working, other than for conditions. Had to use template expression syntax like this: `${{ replace(variables['build.sourcebranchname'], '_', '-') }}` or i would get errors in the pipeline (although the code actually worked, and did the replacement, it still gave errors) In my case i was using my own variable aswell, not one of the "built-in" ones.

Comment: When to use expression or template syntax is quite finicky. Depends on where you declare the var you want to replace on and  where you do the replacement. I have this monstrosity in a job variable: $[replace('${{ lower(variables['build.sourcebranchname'])}}', '_', '-')].

Comment: @JimWolff, right. Using `$[ <expression> ]` or `(${{ <expression> }})` depends on which context is used. It is the difference between runtime and compile time expression, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 9):

As @4c74356b41 pointed out. You can try adding powershell scripts to replace the Build.SourceBranch in your yaml build definition. And output the new sourcebranch to a new variable. Then you can use the new variable in the next steps.

Below is just a simple example. [Click here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) for more information

1, replace "/" to "_" for SourceBranch and set the replaced value to variable newSourceBranch

```
- powershell: |
    $newbranch = "$(Build.SourceBranch)" -replace "/", "_"  
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=newSourceBranch;isOutput=true]$newbranch"
  name: branchsetter
```

2, Use the newSourceBranch in the following steps.

```
- powershell: |
    write-host "$(branchsetter.newSourceBranch)"
```

Comment: It helped me to replace $(Build.Repository.Name) from ```workspace/reponame``` to ```reponame```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do something like that natively yet, what I've been doing is the following:

```
  - bash: |
      date=$(date --rfc-3339=ns | sed "s/ /T/; s/\(\....\).*-/\1-/g")
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=CONTAINER_BUILD_TIME]$date"
```

basically using a script step to set a specific value for a specific variable, and later on you can use it like you normally would: `$(date)`

Comment: Thanks, Not sure I have sed on the windows build though.

Comment: well, you can easily use powershell on windows and use `-Replace` to replace something in the string