# AzurePipeline Build.Repository.Name replace unwanted prefix

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

In Azure Pipleine YAML version the Build.Repository.Name predefined variable contains `workspace/reponame` value in my case.

I wanted to remove the `workspace/` prefix and use the result in a following step.

I tried many ways but without success, but it seems the replace expression maybe be good for me.

One tried solution:

```
variables:
  myVariable: $[replace(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'workspace/', '')]

  steps:
    - bash: echo $(myVariable) # show nothing
```

As i read in documentation the `Build.Repository.Name` does not accessible in this phase
The following runtime call show the correct value

```
steps:
  - bash: echo $(Build.Repository.Name) # shows: workspace/reponame
```

Can I do something similar, and what is the correct way?

```
- bash: echo $(replace('$(Build.Repository.Name)', 'workspace/', ''))
```

Comment: Hi @KevinLu-MSFT thanks, I found a similar solution to 2. suggestion before you write (you did that:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817659/how-to-replace-in-variable-strings-inside-azure-pipelines-yaml ), so i implemented that, but actually waiting for a PR merge. When success I will be mark to best answer. The general problem it seems, the ```Build.Repository.Name``` does not exist on this phase, but later in tasks yes.

Comment: Hi @wia . Thanks for your update. will wait for your good news

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my test, the replace expression could work fine.

Since my repo name does not contain `/`, I switched to another predefined variable(`$(build.sourcebranch)` (e.g. `refs/heads/master`)) for testing.

Here are two methods:

1.Replace expression:

```
variables:
  myVariable: $[replace(variables['BUILD.SOURCEBRANCH'], 'refs/heads/', '')]

steps:
  - bash: echo $(myVariable)
```

2.Bash script:

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        SUBSTRING=$(echo $(BUILD.SOURCEBRANCH)| cut -d'/' -f 3)
        echo $SUBSTRING
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvalue]$SUBSTRING"
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
       echo $(myvalue)
```

**Result:**

[image]

In your case, you could try the following bash script:

```
steps:
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        SUBSTRING=$(echo $(Build.Repository.Name)| cut -d'/' -f 2)
        echo $SUBSTRING
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvalue]$SUBSTRING"
  - task: Bash@3
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
       echo $(myvalue)
```

Comment: The second one is implemented but with power shell, as I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817659/how-to-replace-in-variable-strings-inside-azure-pipelines-yaml#answer-57847395)

Comment: $(Build.SourceBranchName) returns per documentation "The last path segment in the ref. For example, in refs/heads/main this value is main." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: a git repository cannot have a slash in the name, don't know about other silly VCS like TFS but don't think so