# Using 'replace' expression in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build and tag a container image based on the git branch I'm building.
ADO has two options for the branch name:
`Build.SourceBranch` eg. `refs/heads/rc/1.0.0` or
`Build.SourceBranchName` eg. `1.0.0`

However I want to tag my image using `rc1.0.0`, and I figured that should be possible by initially in my yml defining a variable using:

```
variables:
  temp: ${{replace('$(Build.SourceBranch)', 'refs/heads/', '')}}
  dockertag: ${{replace('$(temp)','/','')}}
```

However when I `bash: echo '$(dockertag)'` it produces `refs/heads/master` for the master branch where I would have expected `master` instead.

I'll setup a separate pipeline to test this, but I figured possibly I'm doing something obvious wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing characters in strings and branches has been covered here:
[How to replace in variable strings inside azure-pipelines.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817659/how-to-replace-in-variable-strings-inside-azure-pipelines-yaml)

In short try:

```yaml
variables:      
  suffix: $[replace(variables['build.sourcebranchname'], 'refs/heads/', '')]
```