# How to replace value in Azure Pipelines YAML

Tags: azure, expression, azure-pipelines-yaml

What is the correct syntax for replacing and removing a particular value in a parameter in a Azure YAML pipeline?

my pipeline:

Parameters:

```
 - name: App_Name
   type: string
   values: 
          - ABC_CARD_GAME
          - ABC_CARD_GAME2
          - ABC_CARD_GAME3

Echo ${{parameters.App_Name}}
```

My desired result would be: card-game

*making it lower case, remove ABC, and replace (_) with (-)

Comment: Check this out- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817659/how-to-replace-in-variable-strings-inside-azure-pipelines-yaml

Answer (score 0):

In-order to convert the parameter value to lowercase and remove ABC and replace _ with - in the Azure YAML pipeline you can use [replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#replace) and [split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#replace) expression available in ADO documentation

Example:

```yaml
pipeline:
  parameters:
    - name: App_Name
      type: string
      values:
        - ABC_CARD_GAME
        - ABC_CARD_GAME2
        - ABC_CARD_GAME3

  steps:
    - script: |
        echo "Original Values:"
        for appName in ${{ parameters.App_Name }}; do
          echo "  - $appName"
        done

        echo "Transformed Values:"
        for appName in ${{ parameters.App_Name }}; do
          transformedName=$(echo $appName | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z' | sed 's/^ABC_//g' | sed 's/_/-/g')
          echo "  - $transformedName"
        done
```

Reference Documents:

[Available Azure Pipeline parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/parameters-parameter?view=azure-pipelines)

[Avaiable Azure Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#split)

[Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57817659/how-to-replace-in-variable-strings-inside-azure-pipelines-yaml)